# XML::LibXML - problem installing the module on a fresh macOS BigSur

Tags: macos, perl, installation, macos-big-sur, xml-libxml

I've been successfully using XML::LibXML module for a while on macOS.

Now I am trying to install it on a new machine with **macOS BigSur**:

- *perl Makefile.PL*
- *make*
- *make test*
- *make install*

However, in "**make test**" I get multiple errors of the kind:

```
t/00-report-prereqs.t .............................. ok
t/01basic.t ........................................ 
Can't load '/Users/lockit/Desktop/TESTS_Irina/XML-LibXML-2.0204/blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.bundle'
for module XML::LibXML: dlopen(/Users/lockit/Desktop/TESTS_Irina/XML-LibXML-2.0204/blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.bundle, 0x0002): 
symbol '_xmlFree' not found, expected in flat namespace by 
'/Users/lockit/Desktop/TESTS_Irina/XML-LibXML-2.0204/blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.bundle' 
at /System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 197.
at /Users/lockit/Desktop/TESTS_Irina/XML-LibXML-2.0204/blib/lib/XML/LibXML.pm line 156.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted 
at /Users/lockit/Desktop/TESTS_Irina/XML-LibXML-2.0204/blib/lib/XML/LibXML.pm line 156.

Compilation failed in require at t/01basic.t line 6.
```

And the module cannot be installed.

Any hints what I am missing and how to fix?

Thanks,
Irina

Comment: I think this is due to one of the backwards-incompatible changes Big Sur made. I think [it has been fixed](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/pull/18407), but I don't think any releases have been made with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [README](https://metacpan.org/source/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0206/README) for the module? It includes the following:

> DEPENDENCIES
> ============
> Prior to installation you MUST have installed the libxml2 library. You can get the
> latest libxml2 version from
>
> http://xmlsoft.org/
>
> Without libxml2 installed this module will neither build nor run.
>
> Also XML::LibXML requires the following packages:
> o XML::SAX - base class for SAX parsers
> o XML::NamespaceSupport - namespace support for SAX parsers
>
> These packages are required. If one is missing some tests will fail.
>
> Again, libxml2 is required to make XML::LibXML work. The library is not just required
> to build XML::LibXML, it has to be accessible during run-time as well. Because of
> this you need to make sure libxml2 is installed properly. To test this, run the
> xmllint program on your system. xmllint is shipped with libxml2 and therefore should
> be available. For building the module you will also need the header file for libxml2,
> which in binary (.rpm,.deb) etc. distributions usually dwell in a package named
> libxml2-devel or similar.

So you need to have libxml2 (and its development header files) installed on your system.

Comment: This is unlikely to be the issue (seeing as the have the library's header files). Big Sur broke the Perl tool chain so that `-lfoo` isn't provided to the linker when needed. This is probably the issue at hand

Comment: libxml2 is installed. Looks like it's an issue with Apple's dynamic linker as described here: https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/issues/381. I installed the suggested ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.58 and this solved the initial issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's an issue with Apple's dynamic linker as described here:

https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/issues/381.

I installed the suggested **ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.58** module and this solved the initial issue.

However, now there is a new error on make:
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- LibXML.bs blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.bs 644
cc -c  -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -g -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector-strong -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -Os   -DVERSION="2.0206" -DXS_VERSION="2.0206"  "-I/System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -DHAVE_UTF8 Av_CharPtrPtr.c
Av_CharPtrPtr.c:6:10: fatal error: 'EXTERN.h' file not found
#include "EXTERN.h"

Any clue?